# Assign Users to next state in workbench module

Tags: workbench

Is there a way around to send a node in next state defined by work bench module to specific user instead of user role.

There is a similar question asked already for which one of the answers says using workbench access module can help, but I am not seeing a way to assign a content to a specific user using workbench access module.

My understanding with workbench access module is we can check access for a content to be accessible with what users, but not to choose any specific user while on the content. I mean to say we can put a check on content access on basis of taxonomy or menu which is supposed to be configured with what users can access it, so its more of hard coding the options and not allowing the user to choose on the fly.

Comment: Are you talking about assigning a node to another user as part of Workbench Moderation?

Comment: @MPD assigning a node to a specific user for reviewing state or any other state

Comment: But is this assignment part of just the Workbench module, or are you using Workbench Moderation to define workflow?

Comment: @MPD looks like I did not frame the question in proper way, found a good contrib module https://drupal.org/project/workbench_assignee, I was looking something close to it. Since question is not clear I will delete it :)

Comment: Keep the question, just rewrite it w/ the links to the modules you are using and clarify it.  Workbench is an important topic, and the various sub-modules can be pretty confusing.

Comment: You can also self-answer, and point to the module you find.  Just make sure everything makes sense for other readers.